# Java heap error memory out of bounds when reading csv files

Tags: java, spring-boot, heap-memory

I have 700 csv files each about 5-7 MB in size. I am using Spring boot. All I need to do is read these 700 csv files. So whenever a new file is added to the directory, the method `fileUpdatedOrAdded()` from the `FileWatcherJob.java` gets called. It does some checks and just tried to read the files essentially.

`FileWatcherJob.java`

```
public class FileWatcherJob implements DirectoryScanListener {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileWatcherJob.class);

    public static final String LISTENER_NAME = "DirScanListenerName";

    private static boolean fileFound = true;

    private ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();

    public void filesUpdatedOrAdded(File[] files) {
        if (fileFound) {

            System.out.println("------------- I am doing it again-------------");
            for (File file : files) {
                logger.info("File Found : {}", file.getName());
            }
            logger.info("ALL THE FILES ARE AVAILABLE NOW");

            if (!readFile.getFileAStored()) {
                readFile.readAllFiles("D:\\FileToRead\\fileA.csv");
            }

            if (!readFile.getFileBStored()) {
                readFile.readAllFiles("D:\\FileToRead\\fileB.csv");
            }

            //Read Miscallenous Files including File A and File B
            if (readFile.getFileAStored() && readFile.getFileBStored()) {
                readFile.readAllFiles("D:\\FileToRead\\");
            }
            fileFound = false;
            logger.info("-------------- I am done -----------------");
        }
    }
}
```

`ReadFile.java`

```
public class ReadFile {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadFile.class);


    private Map<Path, List<String>> fileA = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Path, List<String>> fileB = new HashMap<>();
    private Boolean fileAStored = false;
    private Boolean fileBStored = false;

    private Map<Path, List<String>> miscallenousFiles = new HashMap<>();

    public Boolean getFileAStored() {
        return fileAStored;
    }

    public Boolean getFileBStored() {
        return fileBStored;
    }

    public void readAllFiles(String path) {

        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).collect(toList()).parallelStream()
        ){
            paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                //LOGGER.info("CHECK IF FILE IS REGULAR");
                if (filePath.toFile().exists()) {

                    String fileName = filePath.getFileName().toString();
                    try {
                            LOGGER.info("START LOADING THE CONTENT OF FILE " + fileName);
                            List<String> loadedFile = readContent(filePath);
                            storeAandBFiles(fileName, filePath, loadedFile);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOGGER.info("ERROR WHILE READING THE CONTENT OF FILE");
                        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info("ERROR WHILE READING THE FILES IN PARALLEL");
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private List<String> readContent(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        //LOGGER.info("START READING THE FILE, LINE BY LINE");
        return Files.readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }

    private void storeAandBFiles(String fileName, Path filePath, List<String> loadedFile) {
        //LOGGER.info("START STORING THE FILE");
        if (fileName.contains("fileA") && !fileAStored) {
            fileA.put(filePath.getFileName(), loadedFile);
            fileAStored = true;
        }

        if (fileName.contains("fileB") && !fileBStored) {
            fileB.put(filePath.getFileName(), loadedFile);
            fileBStored = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I keep getting the below error however :

> Job group1.FileScanJobName threw an unhandled Exception:
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I don't understand what the problem is. Can someone please help ?
One weird thing, and my suspicion for the cause of the issue is, that even when there is no new file being added to the directory, the watcher still somehow says that there is new file found in the directory !

Comment: Firstly, I tend to suggest you increase heap memory size of JVM. But lastly, you should read each file by opening than closing this file, then read next file. If you need connecting them together, you use buffer.

Comment: Apparently, couldnt increase heap memory more than  -Xmx1024m. And for reading the file, Since I am reading the files in parallel ... I guess reading and closing of files when reading is done are internally taken care by Parallel Streams.. Correct me if required ?

Comment: Yes, you can increase heap memory size of JVM. But it is temporary, it is a worse practice.

Comment: @DoNhuVy Yes Increasing the heap memory is temporary option. But I do not have it, as I increase memory, increasing memory from 1024 to 2048 gives this error:                                                                                                                " Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Process finished with exit code 1"

Comment: Why do you need to read all files at once? If you describe problem that you are trying to solve, I am sure that a better aproach could be taken.